# Помогите соcтавить SQL запрос в MySql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Пишу вопрос первый раз не судите строго.

У меня есть таблица `manager` в MySql:

```
create table manager (id_manager int, m_manager int, y_manager int);
insert into manager values (777777, 5, 2022), (777777, 9, 2021), (777777, 5, 2021), (555555, 8, 2019), (777777, 1, 2019);
```

Допустим есть переменные php:

```
$m_manager = 07;
$y_manager = 2020;
$id_manager = 777777;
```

Надо составить php запрос в базу который достанет ближайшую запись по дате.
Я завис на этом:

```
mysqli_query($bd, "SELECT * FROM manager WHERE id_manager='$id_manager' *вот тут начинаются проблемы*");
```

По данным из переменных выше достать мы должный запись 05.2021.
В таблице не очень много записей, можно добавить столбец даты или еще чего если это потребуется.
Буду рад любой помощи в решении данного вопроса.
Заранее благодарен.

Comment: А что было непонятно в документации или примерах составления запроса?

Comment: Не могу понять как правильно продолжить запрос по 2 столбцам m_manager, y_manager так что бы достать самый ближний. Я вроде выше объяснил нормально мб вам что не понятно из вопроса вы спрашивайте.

Answer (score 0):

Отсортируйте по году и месяцу по убыванию и возьмите первую запись:

```
SELECT * FROM manager WHERE id_manager='$id_manager' ORDER BY y_manager DESC, m_manager DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Чтобы выбрать строку с ближайшей большей датой используйте запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM manager WHERE id_manager='$id_manager' and concat(y_manager, m_manager) >= "20207" ORDER BY y_manager ASC, m_manager ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Ссылка на [песочницу](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uCGvb8YtF2fcfNYDZMt3oC/0).

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ но мне не надо вывести последнею запись из таблицы.
Вопрос заключался достать ближайшую запись из таблицы к дате которые будут в переменных $m_manager = 07;
$y_manager = 2020;

Comment: решается ровно также. Вам ближайшую большую или меньшую?